# spring mvc application to navigate flow from controller to jsp or servlet of another application

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc application. I want to redirect from controller or jsp to my second application that was developed in plain servlet and jsps.

How can I navigate flow from one apps servlet/jsps  to another apps jsp.

I have used following lines in my controller to navigate:

**First:**

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/http://localhost:9090/MarathiInput/test.jsp");
```

**Second:**

```
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:9090/MarathiInput/test.jsp");
```

Currently my controller is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/transferCertificate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView get(ModelMap map ,HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.sendRedirect("localhost:9090/MarathiInput/test.jsp");
}
```

and in my jsp i am calling :

```
<a href="/transferCertificate" class="sis_nav_link">Generate TC</a> this link
```

Comment: And ? What would you expect, and what happens ? Currently, your question could be closed as *unclear* ...

Comment: actually i am using 1 application in spring mvc and another in another in plain jsp-servlets that means i have 2 war files .

Comment: i just want to call jsp or servlet of second war(app)  from first war(app)

Comment: The question is not only what you want, but also what happens with your tries.

Answer (score 0):

You have small errors in both tries, but both can be used.

Assuming method controller is declared to return a ModelAndView you can use :

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:http://localhost:9090/MarathiInput/test.jsp");
```

If it is declared to return a String :

```
return "redirect:http://localhost:9090/MarathiInput/test.jsp";
```

Alternatively provided the controller method has the response as parameter, you can do the redirect in controller, but as you have already processed the response, the method must return null :

```
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:9090/MarathiInput/test.jsp");
return null;
```

So you could use :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/transferCertificate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView get(ModelMap map ,HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:9090/MarathiInput/test.jsp");
    return null;
}
```

or simply :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/transferCertificate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(ModelMap map ,HttpServletResponse response) {
    return "redirect:http://localhost:9090/MarathiInput/test.jsp");
}
```

But make sure that the link includes the servlet context and servlet path :

```
<a href="/application/dispatcher_servlet_path/transferCertificate" class="sis_nav_link">Generate TC</a> this link
```

Comment: my controller is  this  @RequestMapping(value = "/transferCertificate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView get(ModelMap map ,HttpServletResponse response) {
  response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:9090/MarathiInput/test.jsp");
 }    and in my jsp i am calling <a href="/transferCertificate" class="sis_nav_link">Generate TC</a>  this link

Comment: it actually calls to http://localhost:9090/MarathiInput/test.jsp this url when i right click on my Generate Tc link and say open in new tab..  only that time it works otherwise it does not call to jsp

Comment: plz tell me what to do

Comment: can i able to load the test.jsp page in div tag of some other jsps